# Trying to throw 400 when there is an extra key value pair which is not defined in the @RequestBody bean

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
@Data
@Getter @Setter
public class S3UploadRequest {
    private String fileName;
    private String applicationName;
    private String content;

}

 @PostMapping(value = "/writeFileToS3", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public @ResponseBody
    ServiceResponse validateAndUploadFileToS3(@RequestBody S3UploadRequest requestParam,
                                              HttpServletRequest request,
                                              HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse){
/*method body*/
}
```

Now when I pass below json request:

```
{
"fileName" : "abc",
"applicationName" : "abc,
"content" : "abc"
}
```

This works fine.

Now, when I add an extra key,value pair in the request

```
 {
    "fileName" : "abc",
    "applicationName" : "abc,
    "content" : "abc",
    "extraKey" : "extraValue"
    }
```

Now I want to throw 400 because there isnt any "extraKey" field defined in the bean but it neglects the additional key value pair which is "extraKey":"extraValue" and ends the request with 200OK.

How can I achieve this?

Yes, I can do this by considering rawtype as input like

```
  public String method(@RequestBody Map<String,String> request){
    }
```

Now I'll iterate Map and compare every key and throw Validation Exceptio with 400 status code for the keys which are not present in the map.

But how can I achieve the same thing using @RequestBody with Bean?